# Why don't XML Documentation Comments work in a top level C# program?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-core

When I create a C# project with top level statements, xml comments before a method don't work.

For Example in this code after writing three slashes (///), there should appear an xml comment(like shown below) and after hovering on the method Visual Studio should show description of the method:

```
Summarize(15, 35);

/// <summary>
/// Description.
/// </summary>
int Summarize(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the example code?

Comment: Just a couple of reminders - they're not strictly part of the C# language itself (they're just a comment so far as the language is concerned) and top-level statements was primarily motivated for quick-and-dirty samples, tutorials or experiments (which tends to be at the opposite end of a "spectrum" with XML documentation towards the other end)

Answer (score 3):

Your `Summarize` method is an example of a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions). Although local functions are supported by [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements), they do not support triple-slash comments. This has been [raised as an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2110) on GitHub, but it's not clear whether Microsoft will address it.

Meanwhile, you have potential workarounds. The most obvious (other than not using top-level statements) is to use double-slash comments on local functions. However, this won't enable some of the niceties afforded by triple-slash comments, such as IntelliSense integration and documentation generation.

Another option is to wrap your function in a static class defined at the end of `Program.cs`, like this:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Triple-slash comment works!
    /// </summary>
    public static void Summarize() {}
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
Utilities.Summarize();
```

You may want to put this class in a separate file. If you put it in `Program.cs`, it must go at the bottom because of the rule that top-level statements must precede type declarations.